# How to replace unicode dicts values and return to unicode format in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column named "metadata" in unicode format, as it can be seen below:

print(df.metadata[1])

```
u'{"vehicle_year":2010,"issue_state":"RS",...,"type":4}'
```

type(df.metadata[1])

```
unicode
```

I have other column in this dataframe named 'issue_state_update' and I need to change the values from issue state from what is in the metadata to the data in the metadata's row in 'issue_state_update'  column.

I have tried to use the following:

```
for i in range(len(df_final['metadata'])):
    df_final['metadata'][i] = json.loads((df_final['metadata'][i]))
    json_dumps(df_final['metadata'][i].update({'issue_state': df_final['issue_state_update'][i]}),ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
```

However what I get is an error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What I need is to have exactly the same format as before doing this change, but with the new info associated with 'issue_state'

For example:

```
u'{"vehicle_year":2010,"issue_state":"NO STATE",...,"type":4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a DataFrame (DF) that looks something like:

[screenshot of a DF I mocked up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cApMV.png)

Since you're working with a DF you should manipulate the data as a vector instead of iterating over it like in standard Python. One way to do this is by defining a function and then "applying" it to your data. Something like:

```
    def parse_dict(x):
        x['metadata']['issue_state'] = x['issue_state_update']
```

Then you could apply it to every row in your DataFrame using:

```
    some_df.apply(parse_dict, axis=1)
```

After running that code I get an updated DF that looks like:
[updated DF where dict now has value from 'issue_state_update'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyVxp.png)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did not understand well your answer. My main problem are the formats of unicode to dict and returning to unicode

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found the answer. I don't know how efficient it is, but it works. Here it goes:

```
def replacer(df):
    df_final = df
    import unicodedata
    df_final['issue_state_upd'] = ""
     for i in range(len(df_final['issue_state'])):
        #From unicode to string
        df_final['issue_state_upd'][i] = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_final['issue_state'][i]).encode('ascii','ignore')
        #From string to dict
        df_final['issue_state_upd'][i] = json.loads((df_final['issue_state_upd'][i]))
        #Replace value in fuel key
        df_final['issue_state_upd'][i].update({'fuel_type': df_final['issue_state_upd'][i]})
        #From dict to str
        df_final['issue_state_upd'][i] = json.dumps(df_final['issue_state_upd'][i])
        #From str to unicode
        df_final['issue_state_upd'][i] = unicode(df_final['issue_state_upd'][i], "utf-8")
    return df_final
```